# Ensure at least one checkbox is selected - Django Forms

Tags: django

I'm using Django's forms functionality to create a signup page. I've three checkboxes (BooleanField's) and I want to implement validations to ensure that the user enters at least one option.

This is the registration template

```
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
           {{form.is_student}} 
           <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1"> &nbsp{{form.is_student.label}}&nbsp</label>
           {{form.is_teacher}} 
           <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2"> &nbsp{{form.is_teacher.label}}&nbsp</label>
           {{form.is_parent}} 
           <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio3"> &nbsp{{form.is_parent.label}}&nbsp</label>
       </div>
```

This is form.py

```
class SignUp_Form(forms.ModelForm):
is_student = forms.BooleanField(label='Student', required=False, )
is_teacher = forms.BooleanField(label='Teacher', required=False)
is_parent = forms.BooleanField(label='Parent', required=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the right way to do that. I would say to use one of the below methods.

1. Change the form fields to radio buttons. In this way you can tell the user to select one of the above and mark that field as required=True.
2. Or the other way is write a js function to check at least one is selected before submission.

I would personally feel to go with the first one as it makes more good way of a programmer.

Comment: Nope, he said "At least one" and not "at most one"

Comment: Yeah in the moment of thinking i missed that out, thank you @AhmedI.Elsayed

Comment: Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

THe right way to do that is to create a multiple choice required field with three choices.